# Retrieve class name from a Php::Value at PHP-CPP

Tags: php, c++, php-extension, php-cpp

Working on a small extension for PHP using PHP-CPP, I receive at C++ side, an array with objects and I need retrieve the class name of it. The object Php::Value didn't looks like have any method for it.

Similar as i do at HNI in this extension:
https://github.com/mcuadros/bson-hni/blob/master/src/encode.cpp#L86

Comment: Any chance you could do something with `__CLASS__` in it? http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: `__CLASS__` is for PHP at the object scope. :/

Comment: Yeah, never tried to do what you want - was hoping you might be able to come up with some trick :) I am curious myself now that you asked it hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there is no special method to determine the classname in C++ in the Php::Value object. The best way to determine the classname is thus to use the Php::call method to call the get_class method in PHP userspace:

```
std::string classname = Php::call("get_class", object);
```

Where object is one of the objects in the mentioned array.